# try/catch vs null check in java

Tags: java

Sometimes I face I must write a piece of code like this (usually it have more nested if and more complex structure but for the example is enought)

```
public void printIt(Object1 a){
  if (a!=null){
     SubObject b= a.getB();
     if (b!=null){
         SubObject2 c=b.getC();
         if(c!=null){
             c.print();
         }
     }
  }
}
```

when I dont need to know what failed and if something is null do nothing, an approach could be

```
public void printIt(Object1 a){
    try{
      a.getB().getC().print();
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong in this second form like performance or other kind of issues?

Comment: Exceptions are not designed with standard program flow in mind, they're designed for exceptional circumstances.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621762/java-if-vs-try-catch-overhead

Comment: Do not catch `RunTimeException`'s, avoid it instead.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the definition of the code you are using if you have to deal with so many nulls.

Comment: A related question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490770/what-is-faster-try-catch-or-if-else-in-java-wrt-performance?lq=1

Comment: @Eng.Fouad RuntimeExceptions are not always avoidable, that's why they are "runtime".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The exception version (similar to chains using Groovy's safe-navigation operator `?.`) makes it really easy to take the Law of Demeter (or as I call it, Demeter's Strongly-Worded Suggestion) and make it your plaything for the night.

Similarly, deeply-nested `if`-statements leads to difficult-to-read code, and underneath it all, the same "violation" exists, and the cyclomatic complexity of such methods is high.

```
public void printIt(Object1 a) {
    if (null == a) {
        return;
    }

    SubObject b = a.getB();
    if (null == b) {
        return;
    }

    SubObject2 c = b.getC();
    if (null == c) {
        return;
    }

    c.print();
}
```

I'd rather see LAMs (Little Auxiliary Methods) in appropriate places that encapsulate the checks and pretty much eliminate the need for the question altogether.

Comment: You beat me to it! Though, as a side note, I'm sure there's a way for the theoretical a, b and c to never be null. It's just a case of coding them differently.

Answer (score 12):

Yes.  The second version will have terrible performance.

Don't use exceptions for normal control flow.  Effective Java item 57: use exceptions only for exceptional situations.

==UPDATE==

Even ignoring performance issues (exceptions are faster than they once were, according to my [benchmark](http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/run/wasserman.louis@gmail.com/com.google.common.collect.NullCheck), but not nearly as fast as a simple if check), it's really code-smelly to use exceptions for standard program flow like this.  JVM bytecode has special optimizations it can do for null checks, even in `if` statements.  The first code sample is vastly preferred.

Comment: That's simply not true. Exceptions in Java do not incur the performance hit that they used to.

Comment: Citation, please?  (And which Java version?  I've done recent benchmarks indicating otherwise.)

Comment: Also, even if exceptions are significantly faster than they used to be, I would be pretty surprised if they were as fast as just a basic `if` check.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL, their performance may have increased in newer JVM versions, but I still bet it is nowhere near to that of a standard null check. Making a snapshot of the stack trace in itself is a very costly operation.

Comment: Furthermore "not incuring the performance hit that they used to do" doesn't mean that they're not slow.

Comment: Okay, I have a Caliper benchmark with hard numbers!  I will grant, @MДΓΓБДLL, that exceptions are significantly faster than I expected -- but not faster than a standard null check.  Data (and hardware details, and JVM version) at http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/run/wasserman.louis@gmail.com/com.google.common.collect.NullCheck, source of the benchmark at https://gist.github.com/2071935 .

Comment: @LouisWasserman - I wouldn't place a lot of faith in that benchmark.  For a start, it is ignoring the effect of stack depth.  (The cost of creating a exception object is proportional to the stack depth, since the constructor has to capture stack frame details in case a stack trace needs to be generated.)

Comment: I agree -- but that makes me think that the benchmark actually _underestimates_ the cost of exceptions.  The stack depth in an actual program would be much greater, with a correspondingly increased performance cost.  But even with tiny stack depth, the `if` wins.

Answer (score 9):

```
public void printIt(Object1 a){
    if(a==null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("a was null, but this is not allowed here."),
    }
    [...]
```

Fail fast and fail hard. If a shoud not be null, throw an Exception. This will make your code more stable and reliable.

So if I would have to decide between your a) and your b), I would choose a). But if a mustn't be null there, you would hide an error-situation.

Answer (score 8):

The wrongest part of the second version is that when a NPE happens inside the `getB()`, `getC()` it will be silently ignored. As already mentioned, exceptions are for exceptional cases.

Answer (score 2):

Using exceptions is always a bad idea in terms of performance, no matter how slow the mechanism used to be and is now. Whenever an exception is thrown, the full stack will be unrolled to create the stack trace. Thus, like Lois Wasserman said, you should not rely on them for (regular) program flow but for exceptional cases.

The nested ifs aren't the definition of beauty, but will give you the ability to print additional information like 'B is null' etc.

Comment: Actually exception throw/catch can be optimised away, so performance is not always bad (although you might not want to rely upon that).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is use version A.

It is generally considered "bad design" to use Exceptions for flow control. Exceptions are for the "exceptional", especially NPEs which are totally avoidable using null checks. Further, using null checks, you can tell (ie log) *which* term is null (you won't know where the null is with your version B).

Note that performance is *not* an issue any more throwing exceptions (the stack trace for example is only built if you use it). It's a matter of clean code.

However, there are some case where using exceptions for flow control is unavoidable, for example the exceptions thrown from SimpleDateFormat.parse(), because there isn't a reasonable way to tell before making the call that your input is not parsable.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely (a) but you should restructure the method to avoid nesting the if statements as mentioned in a previous answer. Exceptions are not the performance hit they once were but are still *much* slower than checking for null and should never be used for program flow control like this. If an object can be null you should check for it but if it is not allowed you should fail fast at the point you assign the object reference. In many circumstances you can have default implementations (empty list is a good example) to avoid nulls altogether which results in much cleaner code. Avoid nulls whenever you can.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 optional:

```
Optional.ofNullable(a)
            .map(Object1::getB)
            .map(SubObject::getC)
            .ifPresent(Object2::print);
```

Answer (score 0):

A code should never include exception handlers for unchecked exceptions. A null check should always be used for an object reference which has a chance of being null.

Answer (score 0):

If you migrate to Java 8 you can use [Optional](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) and Lambdas. First, you need to rewrite your classes to return `Optional` of each type:

```
class Object1 {
    private SubObject b;

    Optional<SubObject> getB() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(b);
    }
}

class SubObject {
    private SubObject2 c;

    Optional<SubObject2> getC() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(c);
    }
}

class SubObject2 {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "to be printed";
    }
}
```

Now, you can chain the calls without the risk of NullPointerExceptions in a concise way:

```
a.getB()
    .flatMap(SubObject::getC)
    .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

See the Oracle's article [Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) for more information.