# Is there a better way to do an empty check in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

This might look like a primitive question or a this could be done by a simple utility library method that I don't know about.

The goal is to check the value of a boolean field that is nested under two objects.

```
private boolean sourceWebsite(Registration registration) {
    Application application = registration.getApplication();
    if (application == null) {
        return true;
    }

    Metadata metadata = application.getMetadata();
    if (metadata == null) {
        return true;
    }

    Boolean source = metadata.getSource();
    if (source == null) {
        return true;
    }

    return !source;
}
```

I know this could be done in a single `if()`. I have added multiple `if`s here for the sake of readability.

Is there a way that we could simplify the above `if` statements and have a simple utility class that returns the value of `Boolean source` if the parent objects or not null?

Comment: try StringUtils from apache utils

Answer (score 39):

You can use [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) in this way:

```
private boolean sourceWebsite(Registration registration) {
    return Optional.of(registration)
        .map(Registration::getApplication)
        .map(Application::getMetadata)
        .map(Metadata::getSource)
        .map(source -> !source)
        .orElse(Boolean.TRUE);
}
```

In short, this will return `true` if any of the getters returns null, and `!Metadata.source` otherwise.

Comment: `Boolean.FALSE::equals` instead of `source -> !source` if you really love method reference

Comment: I think you meant ` Optional.ofNullable()`

Comment: @dehasi No, I meant `Optional.of` (the original code doesn't return `true` if `registration` is null). `registration` is assumed non-null

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I've upvoted :)

Comment: Return type is `boolean` so `.orElse(true);` would be better.

Comment: @user11153 why would it be better?

Comment: @ave4496 One unboxing less and also shorter code.

Comment: @user11153 The parameter requires a Boolean.. you give it a boolean and so it has to be boxed. It's not one unboxing less but one boxing more

Comment: @ave4496 because `true` reads more cleanly than `Boolean.TRUE`.

Answer (score 15):

The following will return true if any one of is null. If all values are not null, it returns `!source`.

```
private boolean sourceWebsite(Registration registration) {
      return registration.getApplication() == null 
      ||     registration.getApplication().getMetadata() == null
      ||     registration.getApplication().getMetadata().getSource() == null
      ||    !registration.getApplication().getMetadata().getSource();

}
```

**Updated :**

If you want that every getter not called more than once then you can declare variable for every object like

```
private boolean sourceWebsite(Registration registration) {
      Application application;
      Metadata metadata;
      Boolean source;
      return (application = registration.getApplication()) == null 
      ||     (metadata = application.getMetadata()) == null
      ||     (source = metadata.getSource()) == null
      ||    !source;

 }
```

Comment: The null-conditional operator (?.) of c# is for shure a nice thing...

Comment: One problem I see is with that pattern is that it executes getApplication 4 times, getMetadata 3 times and getSource 2 times. If they are all trivial getters, this might not be that much of a problem. But if their implementation is non-trivial (or even worse: not side-effect free) this might become a problem.

Comment: @Philipp yes. But in general getters are trivial.

Comment: In general they *should* be side-effect free, but that assumes that you are working with classes written by people who knew what they were doing and followed good software engineering principles and Java best practices. In the real world, that's a very brave assumption.

Comment: @Philipp yeah thats a  brave assupmtion :D . Thanks for giving a deeper look :)

Comment: If any one of *what*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen any one of the object which he wants to check.

Comment: @Philipp: Wouldn't the code be optimized so that `getApplication` gets called once?

Comment: @EricDuminil You generally can not rely on that. The JVM *might* be able to optimize these method calls away when they are trivial getters, but it might not be able to do that when they have some logic and it certainly won't be able to do it when they have side-effects.

Comment: @EricDuminil see optimisation in updated answer.

Comment: I don't think this really answers OP's question, they specifically said "I know this could be done in a single `if()`. I have added multiple `if`s here for the sake of readability."

Comment: @CaptainMan  isn’t readable? And it contain if () ?

Comment: @KhalidShah To me OP is saying they know they could do it in a single expression with chained `||`s like you've done. That said, after thinking about it a little more, I still think this answer is helpful because other people may not realize this approach even though it seems OP may have been aware.

Answer (score 2):

Another option you can use is a try-catch block. If you get a null pointer exception return true.

```
private boolean sourceWebsite(Registration registration) {
    try {
        return !registration.getApplication().getMetadata().getSource();
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for program logic. Exceptions should be used in case of an unrecoverable state in a program where it's better to stop the entire flow rather than try and recover.

Comment: In general I do agree with you (doing so might make the code harder to follow if it wasn't this short), and I feel that using Optional is correct choice here (assuming you are using a new enough version of java to have access to it). The question asked for a way to handle these checks without several null checks. This will do that.

Comment: @Nzall Exceptions can also be useful in program logic, for instance as a very readable way of checking if a string parses into a number which is very similar to CaptainObvious answer.

Comment: Backing up the comment from Nzall: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255933/6296561 - TL;DR: exceptions are heavy

Comment: Until a NPE is thrown much deeper in one of those methods.

Comment: How can you be certain the NPE was thrown by one of your getters returning null then being used versus one of your getters throwing one internally for "real" reasons? Maybe there's a Map inside that wasn't properly set. You could easily hide an exception you didn't mean to.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9758457/1858327) for why it is bad.

Answer (score -2):

You could do it using a hacky method like this:

```
public static Object get(Object o, String... m) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    if (o == null || m.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    for (String m1 : m) {
        o = o.getClass().getMethod(m1).invoke(o);
        if (o == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Boolean source = (Boolean) get(registration, "getApplication", "getMetadata", "getSource");
return source == null ? false : !source;
```

But I wouldn't do it this way in any serious projects.

Comment: This is bad code in so many aspects: slow, not controlled by the compiler, immune to refactoring aids from the IDE.
Even you recognize that you wouldn't use this in any serious projects. But then: what's the point? No one would bother to post a question or even read the answers for unserious projects.

Comment: It could become a bit better if you passed Methods as parameters instead of strings. It would probably look a bit like `return Optional.of(registration).map(Registration::getApplication).map(Application::getMetadata).map(Metadata::getSource)` so you might as well use `Optional` directly. Still, I don't think you deserved downvotes. This method is still interesting as a thought experiment.