# Is it good practice to catch exception or do a null check for Arrays.copyOf

Tags: java, android

Here is the code snippet :

`myObject[] array = Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length, myObject[].class);`

Is it okay to catch exception instead of checking original against null?

Comment: I would like to ask the question, why you want to do this? Regarding your answer the following answers may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586290/is-catching-a-null-pointer-exception-a-code-smell?rq=1

Comment: Why don't you want an exception?  Exceptions are healthy; they tell you there's a bug and where to look for it.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758457/try-catch-vs-null-check-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to catch exceptions unless your expecting that a particular type of exception might occur. (e.g. email already in system might throw a validation exception, or if data is not found you might get a BadRequest exception)

When applicable, like it seems likely in your snippet, it would be better to do a null check and direct to two different flows depending on what is found. Alternatively, you could instantiate a new array if none is found.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for null is more performant than throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Checking If (value == null) advantages** against exception block

1. Better Performance
2. More clean
3. Less code